# Boosting on facet count

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, lucene

is it possible to boost a document based on how many of the 'same kind' are in the current search result in a Solr/Lucene query?

An example:

I'm looking at 'red dress' and this is the current situation on the facet counts:

```
"facet_counts": {
  "facet_queries": {},
  "facet_fields": {
    "sku_fashion": [
      "children", 
      994,
      "home",
      9,
      "men",
      245,
      "women-apparel",
      2582,
      "women-jewelry-access",
      3,
      "women-shoes-handbags",
      2
    ]
  }
```

For this user a personalisation signal is going to make me blindly boost all the items in the `men` fashion but looks like they are not worth of being pushed up given that they are less than 8% of the entire result set (they are probably junk that is better not to show to the user).

The problem is that I have no idea how to access this info from the function query I use to re-score the documents based on the personalisation signals.

Ideally, I would love to access the above info and kill the personalisation signal telling me to boost the `men` fashion.

Any idea?

Best
Ugo

Comment: I'm not sure about the whole setup - why isn't a small category worth boosting? It sounds like the _exact_ thing worth boosting - i.e. if there are few hits, but they are the most relevant for that person, those should be boosted. I think the issue is that you're considering "men" as a signal for a category that also contains "home", "children", etc. - the signal should be mapped to a distinct classification (possibly man/woman/child/etc., and independent weights should be assigned to each value based on your user's classification).

Comment: Not in this case, I'm afraid. For a query like (e.g.) 'red dresses' most of the results for women. The things for men happening to be in the search result are often junk that is not relevant even if the personalisation tells otherwise. Do you know a guy that thinks a red dress is relevant for him?

Comment: Sure - but that's something you'll have to encode - if a man searches for 'red dresses' and there are _very good hits_ (i.e. hits that would be moved to the top because of the boost), then those should probably be shown first. If not, you're assigning too much weight to that signal compared to what your other signals are and what the document score is. Introducing a category hierarchy where 'dresses' doesn't include the `man`-based categories at all is also a proper option.

Comment: But sure, you can test your theory by making two queries, one to fetch the facets and one that assigns a boost to each of the terms returned - possibly based on the number of hits.